# Can I enter Romania and stay for four weeks with a Schengen visa?

Tags: visas, schengen, romania

I am Indonesian. This month I will go to Iasi, Romania for student exchange. But I will go there after staying one night in France, then take a plane to Iasi, Romania. Do I need to apply for a Romanian visa to enter and stay there for approximately 4 weeks if I already have a Schengen visa issued by France's embassy?

Comment: What's your status in France? What type of visa do you have exactly (multiple-entry or not)? For how long is it valid?

Comment: My status in france is tourist. I am about to travelling in Paris just for one day, go to Romania, back to France, and then back to Indonesia. My type of visa is multiple entry.

Comment: If you have a two-entry visa which is valid before and after your trip to Romania, it would seem OK.

Answer (score 3):

It depends on the exact type of French/Schengen visa you have. With a French residence permit or long-stay visa, it's not a problem. With a Schengen visa issued by France, it's possible if the visa has two entries (or is a multiple-entry visa) and is still valid for the time you would be in Romania. Finally, if you have a single entry visa or a visa expiring during your stay in Romania, then I think you might need a Romanian visa (my reading of the rules is that *transiting* for 5 days might still be possible but I am not sure).

See also the [official rules](http://www.mae.ro/en/node/2040).

Comment: Thank you, but what do you mean 'valid for the time I would be in Romania' ?

Comment: @user16711 I mean that it shouldn't be expired (which yours very likely will not, since you plan to go back to France at the end of the trip). The period of validity should be mentioned on the visa itself.

Comment: All right, thank you so much for answering..it was rlly helpful (: (:

Comment: Wasn't the 5 days transit right the previous rule?  I know that it was like that (and made use of it), but can't find it any more.  Rules changed more than once in the last few years as Romania was due to enter Schengen, then wasn't allowed to after all (on multiple occasions).

Comment: @Szabolcs Yes, it was and the 90-day stay with a multiple-entry Schengen visa is something that has only become possible in 2014. But I am not sure the old one has been abolished (i.e. whether the new rules replace the older ones or just come on top of them), I find the official website very unclear on this (at least it was last time I checked and I can't read Romanian, maybe someone else will be able to shed some light on this)

Comment: I can read Romanian and there doesn't seem to be much more on the Romanian version of those pages than on the English version.  But I did find a link to this (new), which you may want to include in your answer: http://evisa.mae.ro/

Answer (score -3):

Romania, since Jan 1st, 2014, is now also part of Schengen, hence, your visa is also valid for Romania and there is no need to for a multiple entry visa, you never leave Schengen.

@Relaxed is wrong, since this just recently changed.

edit: Sorry, I was wrong, they were supposed to enter by Jan 1st, but they haven't yet, however, it appears you don't need a different visa to enter/exit Romania.

Comment: Romania and Bulgaria are still not part of the Schengen area. However if you have a valid Schengen Visa you can enter Romania, as it were part of the Schengen visa zone (there will still be border checks though). This is the part that was changed recently

Comment: Can you provide a link to show that this has changed?

Comment: Things did change in January but Romania definitely did not join the Schengen area at this date. My answer might be wrong but it would have been different before that date and is certainly not based on the earlier rules.

Comment: Romania and Bulgaria are still [prospective Schengen members](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schengen_Area#Prospective_members), not full ones