# Non-EU citizen Schengen visa via French Embassy

Tags: visas, romania, filipino-citizens

Me and my Filipina wife want to go home to Transylvania, Romania.

Since early 2014, Romania is now a part of the Schengen area. If she has a non-immigrant visa from France, will she be allowed to arrive in Romania?

How much time would it take for the visa processing?

Comment: Note: Romania is not yet part of Schengen but it will and it applies a similar policy as Schengen area.

Comment: If not the one above then: http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/30754/can-i-enter-romania-and-stay-for-four-weeks-with-a-schengen-visa

Comment: Is there an EU citizen schengen visa?

Comment: @andra No, there isn't.

Comment: @Relaxed It was a rhetorical question

Comment: @andra I wasn't sure but I thought it might be best to be completely explicit about it ;-)