# Schengen Visa travel to Romania from India

Tags: visa-free-entry

I am Indian citizen living in India and holding a Schengen Visa to Germany. Can I able to travel to Romania with Schengen Visa.

Comment: If you have a multiple entry Schengen visa you're fine to go to Romania for up to 90 days within the validity period of your Schengen visa.

Comment: @greyshade The question you linked to is completely out of date and contradicts your (correct) answer, see also http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/30754/can-i-enter-romania-and-stay-for-four-weeks-with-a-schengen-visa and http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/35482/schengen-visa-to-travel-to-romania

Comment: @Relaxed sorry, my bad, pasted URL to the wrong question - had intended to link to the second one you linked to.