# Which are the non Schengen countries that allow entry for Schengen visa holders?

Tags: visas, schengen, europe, countries, balkans

There are countries in the Balkan area that allow entry if you have a Schengen visa but am not able find a definite list of all those countries. Knowing that will save me getting a visa for all those countries when I do my mega Euro trip.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Since each of these countries would unilaterally decide whether they recognize Schengen visas and under which conditions, I don't think it's possible to find an official list anywhere. I am marking this answer as “community wiki” so that we can come up with a list:

- **Bulgaria, Romania, Croatia** and Cyprus (all EU members) have rules modelled on those of the Schengen area and allow holders of some types of Schengen visas to visit the country, see [Croatian ministry of Foreign and European Affairs](http://www.mvep.hr/en/consular-information/visas/visa-requirements-overview/), [Romanian ministry of Foreign Affairs](http://www.mae.ro/en/node/2040) and previous questions on this site, e.g. [Can I enter Romania and stay for four weeks with a Schengen visa?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/30754/can-i-enter-romania-and-stay-for-four-weeks-with-a-schengen-visa)
- Official sources are hard to come by but **Albania** apparently allow holders of *multiple-entry* Schengen visa *who have already used their visa at least once* to visit one of the countries of the Schengen Area, see [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visa_policy_of_Albania) and [Timatic](https://www.timaticweb.com/cgi-bin/tim_website_client.cgi?FullText=1&COUNTRY=AL&SECTION=VI&SUBSECTION=00&user=KLMB2C&subuser=KLMB2C).
- **Turkey** provides some concessions to those that normally need visas. If you normally need a visa for Turkey, and you hold a Schengen visa - you may be able to avail the new electronic "e-visa" system. The list of countries whose citizens can avail this exemption [is mentioned on the Ministry of Foreign Affairs' website](http://www.mfa.gov.tr/visa-information-for-foreigners.en.mfa).
- [According to Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visa_policy_of_the_Schengen_Area#Validity_for_other_countries), multiple-entry Schengen visa holders can visit **Bosnia and Herzegovina** for 7 days.
- [According to Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visa_policy_of_the_Schengen_Area#Validity_for_other_countries), Schengen visa holders can visit **Macedonia** for 15 days (with some caveats).
- [According to Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visa_policy_of_the_Schengen_Area#Validity_for_other_countries), Schengen visa holders can visit **Serbia** for 90 days. [The Serbian Ministry of foreign affairs](http://www.mfa.gov.rs/en/consular-affairs/entry-serbia/visa-regime) confirms that information.

  - **Kosovo** - [Foreigners which possess a valid multi-entry Schengen Visa are exempt to obtain a Kosovo Visa to enter, transit or stay in the Territory of the Republic of Kosovo for up to 15 DAYS within a period of 6-MONTHS](http://www.schengenvisainfo.com/non-eu-countries-where-you-can-go-with-schengen-visa/).
- **Montenegro** - According to [Visit Montenegro](http://www.visit-montenegro.com/montenegro-visa-regimes/) holders of Schengen visas may enter, stay in or cross the territory of Monenegro for up to 30 days (but no longer than the expiry of the visa, if the visa expires in less than 30 days).

[image: Schengen country categorisation]

- [According to Timatic](https://www.timaticweb.com/cgi-bin/tim_website_client.cgi?SpecData=1&VISA=&page=visa&NA=IN&AR=00&PASSTYPES=PASS&DE=MX&selDest=Mexico&selTrans=Use+ctrl-key+to+select+or+deselect+transit+point(s)+above&user=OLYMPIC&subuser=OLYMPICB2C) and [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visa_policy_of_Mexico), Mexico offers a visa exemption for 180 days to those holding a valid visa issued by "Canada, Japan, USA, United Kingdom or a Schengen Member State" (this may be further restricted by nationality).

Comment: @CGCampbell Thanks for the tip! Feel free to edit, it's a wiki-answer!

Comment: congrats for civic mindedness on making this one a wiki! It was low hanging fruit for rep hogs.

Comment: Is this applicable to residence permit holders from one of the Schengen countries?

Answer (score 3):

There are 19 countries that are not part of the Schengen Area and which you can visit without a national visa if you do hold a schengen visa.

For more information, please have a look at 
http://www.schengenvisainfo.com/non-eu-countries-where-you-can-go-with-schengen-visa/

Comment: Welcome to the site.  Your source, schengenvisainfo.com, is notorious on TSE for having outdated, unreliable information.  Is there any chance you can find a more reliable source?

Comment: I think it is very reliable source because for every information you find the official government link.

Comment: @Fisnik good point; I hadn't noticed that.