# Staying in Europe (Schengen and non-Schengen) for one year

Tags: visas, schengen

I am an Indonesian passport holder. I have a multiple entry Schengen visa, duration of stay: 90 days, valid for 2 years, issued by the Dutch embassy on November 2014 (valid until November 2016). I will be staying in the Netherlands for 90 days starting on 1 January 2015 and ending on 31 March 2015.

My question is: can I spend 90 days in Romania/Croatia/Serbia/Bulgaria for 90 days starting from 1 April 2015 until 30 June 2015 using my existing Schengen visa? I will then fly back to the Netherlands on 1 July 2015 until 30 September 2015.

My aim is to stay in Europe for one whole year in 2015:

1. 90 days in the Netherlands (January, February and March)
2. 90 days in either Romania or Croatia (April, May and June)
3. 90 days in the Netherlands again (July, August and September)
4. 90 days in either Serbia or Bulgaria (October, November and December)

Comment: Nope maximum 90 days in total in 365(366) days. Else what is stopping people from using this visa as an illegal immigration ploy.

Comment: @DumbCoder It's 90 days in 180 days, not 365.

Comment: @skv That's why the OP is going to Romania, Croatia or Bulgaria, those are not Schengen states.

Comment: Even though Croatia, Serbia, Bulgaria and Romania are outside of Schengen states, one is still allowed to enter these countries using multiple entry Schengen visa. I checked the websites for each of the embassies.

Comment: do you have a link for Serbia? While the other 3 are EU-Members, Serbia is not and I cannot find information about visiting Serbia on Schengen visa.

Comment: @Dirty-flow I don't have a link but some countries apparently do accept Schengen visas unilaterally, see http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/38706/which-are-the-non-schengen-countries-that-allow-entry-from-a-schengen-country/38708

Comment: http://www.mfa.gov.rs/en/consular-affairs/entry-serbia/visa-regime - here it's. But it's a new rule (from 30.10.2014)

Comment: Here is the link for Serbia http://www.abudhabi.mfa.gov.rs/newstext.php?subaction=showfull&id=1415515476&ucat=19&template=Frontpage3&

Comment: NO VISA REQUIRED FOR TRAVEL TO SERBIA FOR HOLDERS OF SCHENGEN VISA, USA VISA, UK VISA AND OTHER EU COUNTRIES’ VISA FROM 8TH NOVEMBER 2014

Comment: @Relaxed - It seems you are wrong. Checked with a friend who has a 1 year ongoing Schengen visa and it is 90 days on his visa, for a year.

Comment: @DumbCoder No, it's not, see annex VII of the [Schengen Visa code](http://eur-lex.europa.eu/legal-content/EN/TXT/?uri=CELEX:02009R0810-20131018). How did your friend check, incidentally? The visa sticker will have either “90” or “XXX” under the “maximum stay” rubric, never more than “90”, but, if the visa is valid for more than six months, it means 90 days per 180-day period. There is no provision to issue a visa limited to 90 days in a whole year.

Answer (score 7):

You could probably do something like that without falling foul of the [90-day maximum stay rule](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/13183/about-schengen-90-180-rule) but there are two problems, a small one and a big one:

- The small one: The day you go from the Netherlands to, say, Romania counts in both countries (except if you fly around midnight?). By my count, if you stay exactly 90 days in the Netherland and then another 90 days in Romania, you will miss one day when coming back to the Schengen area and possibly have some trouble entering Romania (see comments). You need to stay at most 89 days during the first stay in the Netherlands or spend a few days in a third country for this to work, on a purely arithmetic level.
- The big one: You are kind of bending the rules, Schengen visas are intended for short stays and visits. What you are considering is awfully close to living in the Netherlands for half a year with some trips in-between, which is not what your visa is for. Did you submit this itinerary when applying for it?

Remember that border guards can always ask about the purpose of your stay, refuse entry or even cancel your visa if they believe you will do something else than what you claimed you would do or have obtained the visa fraudulently. They have some discretion there, it's not enough to be clever and to fulfill the maximum stay requirement.

My guess is that it *might* work, at least once, but I don't really know. It's possible that going to other Schengen countries, travelling in and out the Schengen area more frequently and cutting a month or two here and there to avoid the impression that you are misusing the visa to stay in the Netherlands could help too.

Comment: @skv  Where did you find this? I was actually looking for authoritative information about that as I remembered a rule like that. But the EU regulation is not too clear about it and the Romanian foreign ministry website is a mess. It would be one more reason to stay 89 days instead of 90…

Comment: http://www.mae.ro/en/node/2040 this mentions "Also, the right of stay in the territory of Romania shall not exceed the right of stay granted as per the visas/residence permits issued by Schengen Member States." so would that be interpreted as a stay of 89 days in Nederlands and 2 days in Romania as "exceeding the right of stay granted"?

Comment: @skv The English is so poor that I always have trouble making sense of this website…

Comment: That's true :) but with that clause, I think someone will clearly see an issue somewhere in the OP's plan

Comment: @skv Please don't delete the first comment, I think it's relevant plus I made a reference to it and removing it makes the conversation hard to follow.

Comment: Sorry, I had to edit the link and it did not allow me to, sorry I will take this in mind in future

Comment: +1, this answer is fine. Since the OP has a MULTIPLE ENTRY and everything he plans falls within the registration period, then he *should* use the Schengen day calculator to get the EXACT entry/exit dates to comply.  The September exit needs to be on the 28th for example.

Comment: @GayotFow will Romanian' clause that I had commented be not a problem, seems an interesting loop hole

Comment: USER MANUAL FOR THE SHORT-STAY "SCHENGEN" CALCULATOR http://ec.europa.eu/dgs/home-affairs/what-we-do/policies/borders-and-visas/border-crossing/docs/short_stay_schengen_calculator_user_manual_en.pdf

Comment: Stays in Bulgaria, Croatia, Ireland, Romania, Cyprus and the United Kingdom shall not be taken into account as they are not (yet) part of the Schengen area without internal borders.

Comment: You must be careful with the calculation of this period, as new rules apply starting 18 October 2013.
 
The 180 days period is defined as the period of 180 days preceding each day of stay in the Schengen area. This means that, on any day of your stay in the Schengen area, you must not have stayed more than 90 days over the preceding 180 days.

Comment: @skv, I agree with James' comment. Also with Relax's observation that the OP will face re-examination at the border. A 3rd back-to-back will fail about 97% of the time for that reason (i.e., building up a private life).

Comment: You can use the "Schengen short stay calculator" to help you make sure you will abide by the rules:
http://ec.europa.eu/dgs/home-affairs/what-we-do/policies/borders-and-visas/border-crossing/schengen_calculator_en.html
 
Stays in Romania, Bulgaria, Cyprus, Croatia, the UK and Ireland will be counted separately from stays in the Schengen area, since these countries are either not members of the Schengen-area or only partially apply Schengen-rules.