# Travel in Schengen after Swedish Temporary Residence Permit has expired

Tags: schengen, transition-of-visa-status

I am a US citizen and have been granted a temporary residence permit in Sweden on the grounds of visiting my father who lives there. I first stayed in the Schengen area for the full 90 day period which is allowed on the free US travel visa, and received the temporary residence permit on the last day of this period. It extended my stay in Sweden by 5 1/2 months and only allows me to stay in Sweden. When this extension expires in March, I would like to take some time to travel in the rest of Europe. I want to know if I am legally allowed to do so. I know that US citizens are allowed 90 days in 180 day period, and my 180 days are up in Jan, but I will stay in Sweden until March. Would it be best for me to exit Schengen from Sweden and then reenter through another country? Or do I have to go home?

Comment: I would ask the Swedish authorities first, whether, and if, under which circumstances (hotel/flight bookings, income statements, your father acting as a sponsor?), they would issue a Schengen tourist visa in March. If they say that they won't because you stayed in Schengen for >90 days, I guess that SIS will tell all other countries to turn you down as well.

Comment: @Alexander There would only be an entry in the SIS if you have been banned for some violation. Otherwise, it's the entry/exit stamps that would be an issue.

Comment: @Relaxed So it would be no problem if I had two passports? Stay 90 days out of 180 on each of them, leaving Schengen only for the stamps? Can't believe that...

Comment: @Alexander It would be a problem in the sense that it would be illegal and potentially expose you to prosecution but it's possibly difficult to enforce, yes. Neither the SIS nor the VIS or any other database presently include a full Schengen-wide record of entries and exits as far as I know. And I am not sure it's a big problem either because it only ever comes up for people who have several passports from countries whose citizens don't need a visa.

Comment: In practice you could still be found out because unless you can fly back to your country of residence before reentering the Schengen area, you would present a fresh passport without entry stamps from the country you are coming from (e.g. if you do a visa run to the UK, UK border guards would expect a Schengen exit stamp and Schengen border guards would expect a UK entry stamp and could ask you about the other passport). Furthermore, some countries might have national databases of entries and exits or use APIS data from airlines.

Answer (score 4):

Time spent under a residence permit does not count towards the short-stay limit so in principle it should be possible to get another 90 days when it expires (see [Does tourist visa (90 days) apply after a long-term visa ends in Schengen countries?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/10504/does-tourist-visa-90-days-apply-after-a-working-holiday-visa-ends-in-schengen/24777)).

In any case, leaving and reentering the Schengen area or going back home would not in itself open any right to stay longer. Unlike other countries, the Schengen area has no notion of ‘resetting the clock’, being admitted for a new period of stay or anything like that. Getting a regular short-stay visa is not an option either. If you have exhausted your 90 days, the only solutions to stay longer is waiting the cooling off period out or getting a national visa/permit like your current Swedish residence permit.

But see also [Staying in Europe (Schengen and non-Schengen) for one year](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/39435/staying-in-europe-schengen-and-non-schengen-for-one-year).

Comment: "Unlike other countries, the Schengen area has no notion of ‘resetting the clock’, being admitted for a new period of stay or anything like that."  Huh, I didn't actually know that.  Man, it must suck not having a euro passport. :/