# Schengen countries with special provisions for additional stay by US citizens

Tags: schengen, europe, germany

Some countries, like Denmark, have a special provision allowing US citizens to enter the country for 90 days within 180 days regardless of other stays in the Schengen area.

I heard this is true for Germany as well? Can anyone confirm this? I will be traveling in the Schengen area for 89 days before heading to Germany, and I do not want to be put on some sort of no entry list for violating the Schengen agreement.

Comment: That's not quite correct. Schengen rules also apply in Denmark and Germany (otherwise what would be the point?). There are however some limited exceptions based on older bilateral agreement but they only apply to very few nationalities. Are you by any chance an Australian citizen?

Comment: See http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/39649/us-citizen-90-180- schengen-stay-bilateral-agreements-w-poland-denmark-etc and http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/42081/visa-for-gap-year-in-europe/42083#42083

Comment: @Willeke Australians enjoy many such provisions, see http://australia.nlembassy.org/services/visa/aus-passport-holders-in-eu.html Denmark offers the same to a few other nationalities and there are perhaps one or two more for New Zealand citizens as well but that's about it as far as I know.

Comment: http://www.nyidanmark.dk/en-us/coming_to_dk/visa/Visa_free_travel.htm

The last paragraph on this page lays out the rules. you can stay in Denmark for 90 days within 180 days regardless of your time in other Schengen countries. I am American, but the provision in Denmark applies to American citizens.

Comment: @Marissa Yes, indeed and that's the only one of its kind for American citizens that I know of. Germany has the same for Australians but I am not sure it applies to Americans. In both cases, it's always nationality-by-nationality and not a general rule so you need to add this info to your question.

Comment: Fixing the broken link in my earlier comment, this question is about US citizens: http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/39649/us-citizen-90-180-schengen-stay-bilateral-agreements-w-poland-denmark-etc No authoritative list of countries in the answer however so not really an answer to your question.

Answer (score 5):

In Germany, all bilateral exemptions are regulated in [§ 16 AufenthV](http://www.gesetze-im-internet.de/aufenthv/__16.html) and listed in [Appendix A](http://www.gesetze-im-internet.de/aufenthv/anlage_a.html).

Those exemptions are summarized for official use in section 4.1.3.1 of the [VwV-AufenthG](http://www.verwaltungsvorschriften-im-internet.de/pdf/BMI-MI3-20091026-SF-A001.pdf) (general administrative regulation for the residence act).

Regarding the 90-180 rule exemptions apply to citizens of the following countries (see below for a rough translation):

- Australia

  > Bei der Bestimmung der Dauer von Aufenthalten von bis zu drei Monaten werden Aufenthalte in anderen Schengen-Staaten nicht angerechnet, auch wenn kein Aufenthaltstitel nach der Einreise beantragt wird.
- Chile

  > Bei der Bestimmung der Dauer von Aufenthalten von bis zu 90 Tagen ohne Ausübung einer Erwerbstätigkeit werden Aufenthalte in anderen Schengen-Staaten nicht angerechnet.
- Japan

  > Bei der Bestimmung der Dauer von Aufenthalten von bis zu drei Monaten werden Aufenthalte von Inhabern japanischer Nationalpässe in anderen Schengen-Staaten nicht angerechnet, auch wenn kein Aufenthaltstitel nach der Einreise beantragt wird.
- Canada

  > Bei der Bestimmung der Dauer von Aufenthalten von bis zu drei Monaten werden Aufenthalte von Inhabern kanadischer Nationalpässe in anderen Schengen-Staaten nicht angerechnet, auch wenn kein Aufenthaltstitel nach der Einreise beantragt wird.
- South Korea

  > Bei der Bestimmung der Dauer von Aufenthalten von bis zu drei Monaten werden Aufenthalte in anderen Schengen-Staaten nicht angerechnet, auch wenn kein Aufenthaltstitel nach der Einreise beantragt wird.
- Croatia

  > Bei der Bestimmung der Dauer von Aufenthalten von bis zu drei Monaten ohne Ausübung einer Erwerbstätigkeit werden Aufenthalte in anderen Schengen-Staaten nicht angerechnet.
- New Zealand

  > Bei der Bestimmung der Dauer von Aufenthalten von bis zu drei Monaten werden Aufenthalte in anderen Schengen-Staaten nicht angerechnet, auch wenn kein Aufenthaltstitel nach der Einreise beantragt wird.
- Panama

  > Bei der Bestimmung der Dauer von Aufenthalten von bis zu drei Monaten ohne Ausübung einer Erwerbstätigkeit werden bei Touristen Aufenthalte in anderen Schengen-Staaten nicht angerechnet.
- San Marino

  > Bei der Bestimmung der Dauer von Aufenthalten von bis zu drei Monaten ohne Ausübung einer Erwerbstätigkeit werden Aufenthalte in anderen Schengen-Staaten nicht angerechnet.

All these provisions are similar in their content (but may differ for edge cases): In general for citizens of these countries the German authorities don't count time spent in other Schengen countries as part of a short-term stay.

Specifically for US citizens it mentions in section 4.1.3.1.16 that no such exception applies for short-term stays, so the well-known 90-180 rule for all of Schengen applies.

Comment: Any chance of a translation for those of us who don't speak German?

Comment: @Phil: It's in the paragraph directly below the list. I'll make that more clear.