# Schengen Multiple visa travel free countries

Tags: visas, schengen, countries

I have 6 month validity Schengen visa. I want to in how many countries I can travel?

Comment: You can travel to the countries listed on the first printed line of your visa.

Answer (score 4):

Look carefully at what is written in the "VALID FOR" area in your visa. This is the top line on your Schengen visa. It can say one of the following:

- "SCHENGEN STATES" or "SCHENGEN STATEN" or "SCHENGENER STAATEN" (thanks @burhan-khalid and @phoog) - this means you can visit all 26 Schengen countries. Note that you still cannot spend more time in any other country than in the country which issued you a visa for (you'd need to apply for visa for the country you primarily visit).
- a specific country/countries name. In this case you legally can only visit the country/countries listed. While there are no border/passport checks between Schengen countries and you might be able to sneak in, this is not recommended. If there is any trouble or random police checks, and you're caught up and have your papers checked, you might be banned from future visits into the whole Schengen area. This would be a quite rare case, but I've seen a visa like that, so it certainly possible.

Comment: Notes it may not say "SCHENGEN STATES", it may state "SCHENGEN STATEN"

Comment: @BurhanKhalid Or "STATI SCHENGEN" or "ETATS SCHENGEN" or something similar in any of the member states' languages (and if there was a limited number of languages beside English, German-only would be very very odd indeed).

Comment: Note that this holds for short-stay (type C) visas. A long-stay (type D) visa implicitly allows _short_ stays in the full Schengen area, even if the "valid for" field only lists the issuing member state (which is where the visa allows a _long_ stay).

Comment: @BurhanKhalid and everyone: the German annotation is actually *SCHENGENER STAATEN*.

Comment: @phoog on my visa from the Netherlands its "Schengenstaten"

Comment: @BurhanKhalid yes, that's Dutch and doesn't have a space.

Answer (score 0):

You can travel to all the 26 countries included in the visa. 
[They can also be found here](http://www.diplomatie.gouv.fr/en/coming-to-france/getting-a-visa/article/list-of-schengen-area-member).

Comment: Schengen visas can be restricted.

Comment: Please don't link to schengenvisainfo.c*m. It is a non-official site that exists only to generate page views and ad revenue (which in itself is not so bad), **and** the information it contains is woefully out of date (which is bad). For example, it claims that there's such a thing as type B land transit visas, even through they were abolished in 2010.

Comment: changed already

Comment: (+1) Adding a word about possible restrictions (even if they are uncommon) could be a good idea. Also, under some conditions Schengen visas opens right to stay in some non-Schengen countries so the list might be even longer: http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/38706/which-are-the-non-schengen-countries-that-allow-entry-for-schengen-visa-holders