# Can I travel to Ukraine on a National Visa from Germany?

Tags: ukraine, schengen-visas

There are countries not in the Schengen area that can be visited as long as you have a Schengen visa.

Does Ukraine allow that?

Comment: What is your citizenship?  Ukraine allows visa-free travel for citizens of many countries.

Comment: I'm a Filipino citizen.

Answer (score 4):

Ukraine does **NOT** appear to be one of those countries. There is a good answer to a similar question you can find here:

*[Which are the non Schengen countries that allow entry for Schengen visa holders?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/38706/which-are-the-non-schengen-countries-that-allow-entry-for-schengen-visa-holders)*

Comment: There is no trouble. The chart in the answer there shows clearly which countries in Europe don't accept SCHENGEN. It was not limited to Balkans.