# What are visa-exempt countries one can travel to by having a valid UK visa?

Tags: visas, uk, visa-free-entry

I am looking for a comprehensive list of countries that allow visa upon entry or waive their visa as long as you have a valid UK visa. One example I found is Turkey - they issue e-visa if you have a valid US, Schengen or UK visa. What are the others?

Comment: what's your nationality?

Comment: It's too many to list them all, but a few examples include the CEFTA states, Georgia, Mexico and the Dominican Republic

Comment: @Crazydre not too broad, here's a similar Schengen Q: https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/38706/which-are-the-non-schengen-countries-that-allow-entry-for-schengen-visa-holders

Comment: Member hasn't returned to specify nationality, which I'd assume might affect the visa implications.  Putting on hold for now.