# Croatia entry with new Schengen visa

Tags: visas, croatia

I will have a valid Schengen visa multiple enteries and I have 
Not entered a Schengen zone. It’s a new visa. Can I travel directly 
To Croatia without having to enter a Schengen zone before.

I don’t seem to find clear information in the web regarding this matter.

Thank you.

Comment: @AndrewLazarus wouldn't that question's duplicate ([Which are the non Schengen countries that allow entry for Schengen visa holders?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/38706/19400)) be the better candidate?

Answer (score 2):

The Croatian government [web site](http://www.mvep.hr/en/consular-information/visas/visa-requirements-overview/) looks clear to me.

> Third-country nationals who are holders of: 
>   uniform visa (C) for two or multiple entries, valid for all Schengen
>   Area Member States …
>   [also various other visa types]
>   do not require a
>   visa for transit or intended stays in the territory of Croatia not
>   exceeding 90 days in any 180-day period.

Comment: The important part being that it only indicates that you *possess* a valid visa, without any indication of previous usage.