To which non-Schengen countries can I travel with a Schengen residency?
I am a Schengen resident. With a valid passport and my residency permit, I can travel to Albania for up to 90 days for example. This is regardless of which country I have a passport of.
Which countries, other than Albania, allow for a visa-free entry (or visa on arrival) based on a Schengen residency?

See also https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/38706/which-are-the-non-schengen-countries-that-allow-entry-for-schengen-visa-holders/38708#38708 (not an exact duplicate as it's about visas, not residence permit but the list ought to be similar).

I think Overseas territories of France as well.

Does visa-on-arrival count?

Visa on arrival would work as well. At least there is not a (lengthy and costly) visa application process. I have edited the question to include it.

Are such kind of question too generic? Impossible to keep updated, and it requires someone (e.g. an external site) to scan and update a list regularly, with much risk of outdated information.

@GiacomoCatenazzi While it's of course better if it's kept updated (better make it a community wiki in that case), a list at a given point in time would probably already be useful.

I've just done a quick scan of Timatic (via the Emirates website, looking for "residen" and "EU or Schengen") and did not find anything relevant yet. Saudi Arabia bizarrely has a rule for family of EU residents, but not the residents themselves. Qatar has a rule for "Hayya Entry Permit (A3)" which I have no idea what it is. I think quite a few will accept visas, including D visas, and will probably accept residence permits as well, but I didn't look into it closely.

The question here is a bit different from Which are the non Schengen countries that allow entry for Schengen visa holders?, because it asks about residency holders and not visa holders.
As it was mentioned in the comments, this question is quite generic, but I can think of two cases where an individual with a Schengen residency has visa free access to a non-Schengen area solely for holding a Schengen residency, he wouldn't otherwise even having visa-free travel to the Schengen area. However, they aren't countries but rather overseas territories of The Netherlands and France: French Guiana, Sint Maarten, Aruba and other Dutch Caribbean territories.
Brazilians and Venezuelans who enjoy visa-free travel to the Schengen area still require a visa for French Guiana and the other territories respectively. However, Brazilians and Venezuelans with a valid Schengen residency can travel to these territories only carrying a valid passport and a Schengen residence permit.
In addition, these territories allow visa free travel to any national who holds a Schengen residency.
Edit: other French territories in the Caribbean and beyond, also allow visa free travel for all Schengen residence holders.

(+1) This covers French Guiana but not the French Carribean islands of Martinique and Guadeloupe?

All French territories in the Caribbean and beyond. I edit to add that.

If you were in Sint Maarten, I wonder if you could wander over to Anguilla?

Georgia allows valid visa holders and residents of Schengen countries, Australia, USA, UAE, New Zealand, Bahrain, UK, Japan, Ireland, Israel, Canada, Qatar, Cyprus, South Korea, Oman, Saudi Arabia and Kuwait to enter and stay in Georgia without visa for 90 calendar days in any 180-day period.

Citizens with a residency permit for Schengen countries have visa-free or visa-on-arrival access to various nearby non-Schengen states. Some favored spots for visits include Albania, Serbia, North Macedonia, Moldova, the Philippines, Singapore, Egypt, and São Tomé e Príncipe. For a complete listing of options, this useful online guide provides thorough information: https://www.cntraveller.in/story/33-non-schengen-countries-you-can-visit-with-a-schengen-visa
